# Como pegar o nome da unidade de rede listada

Tags: c#, treeview, driver

Eu estou listando as minhas unidades de rede via *C#* em uma `TreeView`.
Hoje esta aparecendo da seguinte forma:

[image: listagem]

Porem eu quero que apareça o nome completo:

- `C:\Disco Local`
- `J:\Pen Drive X`

Estou usando o seguinte codigo para buscar os drives:

```
foreach (DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
                if (drv.IsReady)
                {
                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
                    node.Tag = drv.RootDirectory;
                    node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
                    node.Text = drv.Name;
                    TwCaminhoArquivo.Nodes.Add(node);

                }
}
```

Sendo que `TwCaminhoArquivo` é a minha `TreeView`.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar a propriedade `VolumeLabel`conforme abaixo.

```
    foreach (DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        if (drv.IsReady)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
            node.Tag = drv.RootDirectory;
            node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
            node.Text = $"{drv.VolumeLabel} - {drv.Name}";
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
```